# How to use FTPlib in python

Tags: python, ftplib

i'm writing an application that is supposed to upload a file to an FTP server.

Here's the code:

```
    try:
        f = open(filename,"rb")
    except:
        print "error 0"
    try:
        ftp = FTP(str(self.ConfigUri))
        print "CONNECTED!"
    except:
        print "CANNOT CONNECT"
    try:
        ftp = FTP(str(self.ConfigUri))   # connect to host, default port
    except:
        print "error 1"
    try:
        ftp.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
    except:
        print "error2"
    try:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f)
    except:
        print "error 3"
    try:
        ftp.quit()
    except:
        print "error 4"
```

I am getting an error at ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f). Any ideas why?

Comment: Try to replace the `except:` lines with `except Exception, e:` and let `print e` in the next line. It will give you more information than simple `print "error 3"`

Comment: Seems like you're in love with boilerplate code. Have you thought about programming in Java? Okay, joking aside - don't ever ever use `try: ... except:`. If you can't handle the specific exception, let it fall through, so that you can see the traceback. Remove all those `except: print ...` lines and tell us what exception you get.

Comment: why are you connecting twice?

Comment: Don't ever ever? I don't get that. What if you want to read a file full of financial transactions, and process each row. Surely if one row contains some error, you still want to continue and process the remaining rows, rather than leaking money all over the floor? So doesn't one use "except Exception"?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the filename is the full path, you should use the basename instead:

```
import os
folder, base = os.path.split(filename)
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + base, f)
```

If not make sure your python is running at the right place:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

What error does the following code report?

```
try:
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        ftp = FTP(str(self.ConfigUri))   # connect to host, default port
        ftp.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f)
        ftp.quit()
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

**EDIT**:
`Error 550?` Looks like access denied error... Does anonymous user have the rights to write into that FTP directory?

Comment: No such fie or directory

Comment: does the file doc.txt exist in the current directory?

Comment: yes, in the local machine current directory

Comment: @Juli: edit your question, with the actual traceback.

Comment: 550: No such file or directory

Comment: @Juli: post actual value of the `filename`

Comment: @Juli: try to `print "<%s>" % filename` just between the login and storbinary and then (still between login and storbinary) `print "<%s>" % ftp.pwd()`

Comment: @Juli: Error 550? Looks like access denied error... Does anonymous user have the rights to write into that FTP directory?

Comment: print "<%s>" % filename: doc.txt

Comment: print "<%s>" % ftp.pwd(): </>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a full path to open the file and you are using that same full path to name the file for ftplib. Instead, `cd` to that directory and name the file with just the file name.

Stealing @eumiro's code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os.path

try:
    with open(fullpath,"rb") as f:
        directory, filename = os.path.split(fullpath)
        ftp = FTP(str(self.ConfigUri))   # connect to host, default port
        ftp.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
        ftp.cwd(directory)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f)
        ftp.quit()
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

If the directory is not on the server, you can make it:

```
ftp.mkd(directory)
```

Or you can omit the ftp.cwd() call and just place the file in the ftp root.

Comment: `directory` is a local directory

Comment: @SilentGhost: I got that. It's possible that the server has the same directory structure or the OP wants to create that. Placing the file in the ftp root would be the most direct test. (My suggestion to split the directory and filename was based on the untested suspicion that ftp.storbinary() does not take paths at all.) Who will be the first to be upvoted on this question? Woooo, the anticipation!